# deleting in tables in a specific order

Tags: sql

Hy,my question is how can i use a procedure in which i can delete data from one table and then from the other to avoid the problem with the REFERENTIAL INTEGRITY, I tried it like this

```
 create procedure usp_Testovi_Delete
 (
 @TestoviID int
 )
 as 
 delete from Testovi
  where TestoviID=@TestoviID
  delete from RezultatiTesta
  where TestoviID=@TestoviID
```

but I need to execute it twice to delete data from both tables , ty for your time and help , I'm using SQL server.

Comment: Reverse the order of the deletes. Are you seeing errors right now?

Comment: Read about delete cascade

Comment: What you are doing is ok. I would just put them between BEGIN TRANSACTION...COMMIT TRANSACTION statements to avoid mishaps.  But if you still want it in one statement, you should modify the foreign key and set delete rule to `Cascade`.

Comment: Its working perfectle when i reverse the delete order ,there are no erors ,thank you guys for your help :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a variety of ways to handle this:

- Delete from the table with the foreign key first.
- Wrap the first delete in a blank exception handler, then delete from the second table, and finally delete from the first table again.
- Disable the foreign keys while you perform the delete, and re-enable them afterward.

They each have advantages and disadvantages :-/